# Invoking method in Main java

Tags: java, methods

```
public class cylinder2
{
public static void sphereOut (double radius, double volume, double area) 
 {             
            Output.showValue("Radius: ",radius);
            Output.showValue("\nVolume: ",volume);
            Output.showValue("\nArea: ",area);

 }//method sphereOut


 public static double getarea (double radius)   
{
  double area;
  area = 4.0 * 3.14 * radius * radius;
  return area;

}//method area


public static double getVolume (double radius)
{
  double volume;
  volume = 4.0/3.0 * 3.14 * radius * radius * radius;
  return volume;

}//method volume

public static double getRadius()
{
  double radius;
  radius = Input.readDouble("Input Positive radius: ");
  while (radius <= 0)

        radius = Input.readDouble(
            "ERROR: " + radius + " is negative;\n"
            + "Please enter a positive Radius: ");

  Output.showValue("You entered ", radius);    

  return radius;

}//method getRadius

public static void main (String [] args)
{

  getRadius();
  double getVolume;
  double getarea;

 sphereOut();

}//method main

}//class cylinder2
```

Some simple code here with a simple question. 
I'm wondering how to invoke my "sphereOut" method later on into my main.

I tried just sphereOut(); and other variations but always error.  Seems like I'm missing something very simple here.

> cylinder2.java:83: error: method sphereOut in class cylinder2 cannot be applied to given types;
>          sphereOut();
>          ^
>     required: double,double,double
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Thats the current error I'm getting back.

Comment: Call the method with it's appropriate arguments in the main.

Comment: according to your stacktrace your **sphereOut()** accepts three parameters. be sure you are passing the corresponding param while invoking the method

Comment: I strongly advise learning the very basics of Java before trying some slightly more complex examples. Try some tutorials, cookbooks, workbooks, anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  From the sample code you've given it looks like you've taken a simple program where everything was inside main() and tried to split things up into separate methods, unfortunately you've forgotten some things.


1. Return values must be saved to a variable or they will be lost. You call getRadius() at the start of your main() but you don't save the value it returns anywhere, once you leave the scope of the getRadius() method you don't have access to the `radius` variable defined in it.


2. You must call methods with an appropriate number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should give parameters to your method `sphereOut(radius, volume, area);`

EDIT :

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  double radius = getRadius();
  double getVolume;
  double getarea;

  sphereOut(radius, getVolume, getarea);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and get back errorr:cannot find symbol

Answer (score 0):

When using main you usually have specified arguments.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  sphereOut(getRadius(), getVolume(2.2), getarea(3.3));
}
```

Comment: getRadius() doesn't have an argument !